# WebStorm: Client and Server at same port

Tags: angularjs, node.js, webstorm

I am new in WebStorm. I have got a sample application that consist two projects: client(angularJs) and server (node.js).

1. When I start server app.js (api that return json), it listening port 7200
2. Wnen start client (AngularJS app) index.html, it works on port 63342

But the api call from client to server does not work. because client ask url

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'api/maa'}).
```

http://localhost:63342/quickstart/src/client/api/maa, but server works on port 7200 (http://localhost:7200/api/maa).

How to fix this, it is possible to launch both server and client on same port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can even start both using the same run configuration. Node.js run configuration has a 'Browser/LiveEdit' tab that allows to launch the browser and debug the client code. Check the 'After launch' checkbox there, specify the URL of the server your front end is served on (`http://localhost:7200`) and enable the 'with javaScript Debugger' option